# NSUserDefault string can't retrieve and convert to double

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsuserdefaults, nsnumber

I'm saving a value to NSUserDefault.

Original value is in double, I convert it into NSNumber and then save it as a string. 
I printed the values while saving and they are set correctly.

When retrieving, i get the string value and convert it into double. But both the string and double value don't give anything. string gives null and double gives 0.000

Saving

```
//convert filtersequcne to NSNumber...finally saved as string

            NSNumber *myDoubleNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:filtersequence];
            NSLog(@"Value being stored in myDoubleNumber %@",myDoubleNumber);


            // save string with input name of filter for that key
            NSUserDefaults *combination = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [combination setObject:[myDoubleNumber stringValue] forKey:input];

            NSLog(@"Value of [mydoublenumber] string value %@",[myDoubleNumber stringValue]);
```

Getting the values back

```
//get input from saved filter
    NSUserDefaults *fetchcombination = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // get the string
    NSString *message = [fetchcombination objectForKey:@"Test"];
    NSLog(@"Value of message %@",message);

    // convert string to double
    double actualdoublecombination = [message doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"Value of double actualdoublecombination %f",actualdoublecombination);
```

Comment: What is the value of `input`?

Comment: Test, i even changed that to "Test"....still same result.

Comment: Did you call `registerDefaults:`?

Comment: Why? If you have and want a number, save the number...

Comment: Can I save a double value as NsUserDefault..... it is a 16 digit number to save, Is it possible?

Comment: @Wain You have to call `registerDefaults:` in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to tell NSUserDefaults what it has to save.

Comment: @NobodyNada, no, you don't have to, it is called to set initial default values that aren't saved to disk and should be irrelevant to this situation

Comment: @Wain Just did some testing.  When I commented out the `registerDefaults:` in my app, the settings stopped saving.  When I un-commented it, they worked perfectly.

Comment: @NobodyNada, then your test is invalid or you have some other issue because registering defaults explicitly does not save anything. By the sounds of it you are never saving (or, you killed the app before the save occurred).

Comment: @Wain Wow!  You're right.  I guess I deleted some code by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you save/read a double:

```
double value = 42.00;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setDouble:value forKey:@"MyDouble"];

double value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] doubleForKey:@"MyDouble"];
```